# Stuck at installing Python tensorflow on Apple M1 chip computer via Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, apple-m1

We are close to end of 2023, but I'd like to ask if anyone has successfully installed the Python tensorflow package via Anaconda on Apple M1 chip computers as of now?

I just recently tried installing tensorflow using the conda install command, but it's always stuck at solving environment.

I then sought to install tensorflow using brew. But since I'm now using Spyder, I'm not sure if the tensorflow package can work with Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install TensorFlow on the M1 chip, but there are some extra steps you have to do. Generally, you have to first install Miniforge, create a virtual Python environment, and then install Tensorflow and its dependencies.

1. Install Miniforge

   `conda config --set auto_activate_base false`
2. Create Virtual Environment (with your version)

   `conda create --name <your evn name> python=<your version>`
3. Activate the env

   `conda activate <your evn name>`
4. Install Tensorflow (dependencies, metal-plugin...)

   `conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps`

   `pip install tensorflow-macos`

   `pip install tensorflow-metal`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I managed to activate a new environment. However, when I reached the "conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps" step, it says tensorflow-deps aren't available from current channels. I searched "apple tensorflow" on anaconda, but it seems the package has been removed. Are there any alternative tensorflow package for M1 chip?